# MySQL - possible to optimise query with 3 sub-queries utilising order by desc limit 1 to retries latest record?

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery

I'm struggling with optimising a query that retrieves some products along with their previously logged pricing details.

Because my 3 sub-queries utilise an order by desc and a limit 1 to return the last logged price, and the log table contains tens of thousands of rows (and will likely contain millions in the long term), it is taking somewhere in the region of 5 seconds to produce the query results (there are approximately 3000 products).

```
SELECT products.*, 
    (SELECT value_new FROM log_actions 
     WHERE action='edit' AND target_entity='net_price_euro' 
     AND target_table='products' 
     AND target_id=products.product_id
     ORDER BY log_time DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS previous_net_price_euro,
    (SELECT value_new FROM log_actions 
     WHERE action='edit' AND target_entity='retail_sterling' 
     AND target_table='products' AND target_id=products.product_id
     ORDER BY log_time DESC LIMIT 1
     ) AS previous_retail_sterling,
    (SELECT value_new FROM log_actions 
     WHERE action='edit' AND target_entity='gp' 
     AND target_table='products' 
     AND target_id=products.product_id
     ORDER BY log_time DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS previous_gp
FROM products
WHERE products.deleted IS NULL ORDER BY products.status asc
```

I have all relevant fields indexed as far as I can tell. Running an EXPLAIN on the above returns the following:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     products    ALL     deleted     NULL    NULL    NULL    3192    Using where
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  log_actions     ref     target_entity,target_id,action,target_table     target_id   4   products.product_id     4   Using where; Using filesort
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  log_actions     ref     target_entity,target_id,action,target_table     target_id   4   products.product_id     4   Using where; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  log_actions     ref     target_entity,target_id,action,target_table     target_id   4   products.product_id     4   Using where; Using filesort
```

I have read up that adding a desc index can improve performance, but on further reading it seems that MySQL does not currently support this.

Comment: How many rows does the query return (e.g. have `deleted IS NULL`)?

Comment: At the moment there are about 3000 rows returned

Answer (score 2):

This query rethinks a little bit the problem. You're right saying the DESC index is not supported yet by mysql, that's why I tried to make a query that orders less times than yours (you order it 3 times):

```
SELECT products.*, 
    l1.value_new AS previous_net_price_euro,
    l2.value_new AS previous_retail_sterling,
    l3.value_new AS previous_gp
FROM products
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT target_id, target_entity, MAX(log_time) AS mx FROM log_actions
            WHERE
                action='edit' 
            AND target_table='products'
            GROUP BY target_id, target_entity
        ) lastvalues ON lastvalues.target_id = products.product_id
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT target_id, target_entity, log_time, value_new FROM log_actions
            WHERE
                target_entity = 'net_price_euro' 
            AND action='edit' 
            AND target_table='products'
        ) l1 ON l1.target_id            = lastvalues.target_id 
                AND l1.log_time         = lastvalues.mx 
                AND l1.target_entity    = lastvalues.target_entity
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT target_id, target_entity, log_time, value_new FROM log_actions
            WHERE
                target_entity = 'retail_sterling' 
            AND action = 'edit' 
            AND target_table = 'products'
        ) l2 ON l2.target_id            = lastvalues.target_id 
                AND l2.log_time         = lastvalues.mx 
                AND l2.target_entity    = lastvalues.target_entity
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT target_id, target_entity, log_time, value_new FROM log_actions
            WHERE
                target_entity = 'gp' 
            AND action = 'edit' 
            AND target_table = 'products'
        ) l3 ON l3.target_id            = lastvalues.target_id 
                AND l3.log_time         = lastvalues.mx 
                AND l3.target_entity    = lastvalues.target_entity
WHERE products.deleted IS NULL 
ORDER BY products.status ASC
```

In this case you could use another index which would include log_time, it would probably speed up the inner joins.

Answer (score 1):

The three inline subqueries are all similar:

```
(SELECT value_new FROM log_actions 
 WHERE action = 'edit' 
   AND target_entity = 'net_price_euro' 
   AND target_table = 'products' 
   AND target_id = products.product_id
 ORDER BY log_time DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

I would add an index on:

```
 (action, target_table, target_entity
 ,target_id, log_time, value_new)
```

The order of the columns in the index does not matter for the first 3 columns but does matter for the last three: `(..., target_id, log_time, value_new)`

Comment: Thank you, I've implemented your suggestion and I have noted a definite increase in performance (typical query time is now about 0.4 seconds). Can I ask you to explain further how this index aids execution time, and particularly why the ordering is of importance? [Edit] - actually on testing within my application I'm still finding a similar performance to the original (5-7 seconds execution).